# Not able to select table, but able to see all table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-rds

I spinned up a new RDS mysql instance on aws. I run different script and was able to create table.I can see the table in workbench and other clients like sql developer but when I run a query it is say table doesn't exist.

My database is testdatabase.
i created table called user. I am able to see in browser and export the data as well. But when I run

```
use testdatabase
select * from user
```

> SQL Error (1146): Table 'testdatabase.user' doesn't exist

It say table does not exist. I searched all forums, I did not export a database or restored from backup. I have admin privilege what need to be done?I created a new database and created tables using scripts.

Comment: how about "show tables" and "select * from information_schema.tables"  to check whether the table exists.. What you "see" is possible the table name belongs to mysql database.